# Can't clone any projects but can push and pull: FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, bitbucket

Now I've tried to clone a project and I can't because of this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

But push and pull works correctly (My SSH keys are working). Even cloning the project that I can push/pull throw this error.

**Clone, pull and push works correctly from github.**

Using:

- Git Extensions 2.48;
- Bitbucket;
- Putty;
- Win 7;

How to solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved partially by creating a local repo and the add the origin remote. Then use push/pull. No need to clone.